# Windows 10 - No Module named 'keras'

Tags: keras, jupyter

I'm new to Python and Jupyter.  I am running Jupyter 6.1.4 and imported keras using pip install keras however when I try to run the import code - I'm receiving the error listed below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFlBi.png)

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**install tensorflow using pip**

`pip install tensorflow`

Then make all your importings like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import  mnist
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import  load_img, array_to_img
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```